# Getting : Error: backingFormData.forEach is not a function using server action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, server

I'm currently working on a project using NextJs version 13.14, and I'm trying to implement a server action. However, I encountered an error that says "backingFormData.forEach is not a function" when I attempt to use the server action. I'm not sure what is causing this issue. Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?

**Error**
[image]
Here's the code snippet where the error occurs:
**Form using tailwind :**

```
 <form className="" action={handleFormAction}>
        <div className="flex flex-col space-y-4">
          <div className="flex flex-col space-y-2">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
              className="border border-gray-300 rounded-md px-4 py-2"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              id="email"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="flex flex-col space-y-2">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input
              className="border border-gray-300 rounded-md px-4 py-2"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              id="password"
            />
          </div>

          <button
            className="bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-md px-4 py-2"
            type="submit"
          >
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

**Sever function**

```
 async function handleFormAction(formData: FormData) {
    "use server";

    const name = formData.get("name");
    // do something
  }
```

**Package.json**
{
"name": "server-action",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint"
},
"dependencies": {
"@prisma/client": "^5.0.0",
"@types/node": "20.4.4",
"@types/react": "18.2.16",
"@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
"autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
"eslint": "8.45.0",
"eslint-config-next": "13.4.12",
"next": "13.4.12",
"postcss": "8.4.27",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
"typescript": "5.1.6"
}
}

**The entire code**

```
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  async function handleFormAction(formData: FormData) {
    "use server";

    const name = formData.get("name");
    // do something
  }
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <header>
        <h2>Login FUllstack</h2>
      </header>

      <form className="" action={handleFormAction}>
        <div className="flex flex-col space-y-4">
          <div className="flex flex-col space-y-2">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
              className="border border-gray-300 rounded-md px-4 py-2"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              id="email"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="flex flex-col space-y-2">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input
              className="border border-gray-300 rounded-md px-4 py-2"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              id="password"
            />
          </div>

          <button
            className="bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-md px-4 py-2"
            type="submit"
          >
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I want to submit form using server action